# SOIL2 with cmake

Tags: opengl, cmake

I'm trying to learn OpenGL from a tutorial, and I need to link SOIL2 to my project.
I tried to write my CMake like this:(all other libs are working, **Cmake gets no error** but I can't include SOIL2.h because of 'SOIL2.h' file not found). I'm working with Clion IDE.

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.15)
project(OpenGL_Tutorial)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 14)

add_executable(OpenGL_Tutorial main.cpp)

find_package(OpenGL REQUIRED)
find_package(SDL2 REQUIRED)


find_package(PkgConfig REQUIRED)
pkg_search_module(GLFW REQUIRED glfw3)

find_library(SOIL2 lib/libsoil2.a)

include_directories(
        ${OPENGL_INCLUDE_DIRS}
        ${GLEW_INCLUDE_DIRS}
        ${GLFW_INCLUDE_DIRS}
        ${SDL2_INCLUDE_DIR}
)


target_link_libraries(OpenGL_Tutorial
        ${OPENGL_LIBRARY}
        ${GLEW_LIBRARY}
        ${GLFW_LIBRARIES}
        ${SDL2_LIBRARY}
        ${SOIL2_LIBRARY}
        )
```

libsoil2.a is located in my lib directory in the project directory
[(see project direcory image)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LIjhd.png)

Thanks!

Comment: You need to add to `include_directories` command call a directory which contains `SOIL2.h` on your machine.

Comment: Please consider posting the completed CMake code that is working in an **answer** post, for the benefit of future visitors to your question!